# Where can I find a file/struct layout for a tcpdump() file?

Tags: parsing, logging, tcpdump

We are capturing packets to a file using [tcpdump()](http://www.tcpdump.org/).  I need to write a program to parse it, does anyone know where I could find a file layout for a dump file created by this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcpdump uses libpcap; there are docs describing the [libpcap file format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) which should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to parse the file is to read it with libpcap; libpcap can be used directly from C and C++, and there are wrappers for a number of other languages.  That way you don't have to know what the file layout is (and you will also be able to read at least some pcap-ng files if your program is using libpcap 1.1 or later).